# SQL Join 2 rows and sum with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have a 3 tables to pull data from and I am mainly concerned with the Inventory table data.
I have the following query with nested selects because I wasn't sure how to use the pivot functions and now I'm dealing with the limitation of my group by functions. I think if I could knock off the I.[Ship Order #] from the end of the code it would work the way I want it to.

```
SELECT  
(Select ShipDate FROM ShipOrder AS S Where S.[ShipOrder#]= I.[Ship Order #]) AS [Ship By]
,(Select [Billing Name] FROM tblCustomers AS C WHERE C.[Key] = 
(Select CustomerKey FROM ShipOrder AS S Where S.[ShipOrder#]= I.[Ship Order #])) AS [Customer Name]
,I.[Type/Size]
,I.Product
,I.[Ship Order #]
,SUM(CASE WHEN I.[Ship Order #]=0 THEN I.[Gross Weight] - I.[Tare] ELSE 0 END) AS Inventory
,SUM(CASE WHEN I.[Ship Order #]>0 THEN I.[Gross Weight] - I.[Tare] ELSE 0 END) AS [Qty Ordered]
FROM INVENTORY I

WHERE I.[Type/Size] = 'W3401 3 3/4'
GROUP BY I.[Type/Size],I.Product,I.[Ship Order #]
```

And here is the result...
But I want the two rows to be combined into 1 row around the Ship Order 13237 value, but showing the max inventory and max qty ordered values.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you want, but looks like you might want to just group by columns from `I`. Use normal joins, not subqueries:

```sql
SELECT  
MAX(s.ShipDate) AS [Ship By]
,MAX(c.[Billing Name]) AS [Customer Name]
,I.[Type/Size]
,I.Product
,SUM(CASE WHEN I.[Ship Order #]=0 THEN I.[Gross Weight] - I.[Tare] ELSE 0 END) AS Inventory
,SUM(CASE WHEN I.[Ship Order #]>0 THEN I.[Gross Weight] - I.[Tare] ELSE 0 END) AS [Qty Ordered]
FROM INVENTORY I
LEFT JOIN ShipOrder AS S ON S.[ShipOrder#]= I.[Ship Order #]
LEFT JOIN tblCustomers AS C ON C.[Key] = s.CustomerKey

WHERE I.[Type/Size] = 'W3401 3 3/4'
GROUP BY I.[Type/Size],I.Product;
```

Notes:

1. Is this a typo: `I.[Ship Order #]=0`? One would normally write `IS NULL / IS NOT NULL`
2. Do we `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`, that depends on the relationships between the tables (i.e. is `I.[Ship Order #]` and `s.CustomerKey` nullable)?
3. Do yourself a favour and give column names that don't require bracketing.
4. Don't store `[Type/Size]` together, split them into separate columns

Comment: 1. Not a typo, the value is literally 0 or something like 13134-14002.When I run it, I get (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.)

Comment: Whoops sorry changed `left join where` to `left join on`. What do you mean, you have an actual row in `ShipOrder` with ID=0? That's a weird thing to do.

Comment: It isn't an index. Actually none of these tables are indexed. I don't have any control over the database other than to do this select query. Which changing WHERE to ON gives this error. Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'ShipOrder.ShipDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Hum, how do you actually want this grouped? Which of the columns do we `sum` or `count`, which do we need each distinct value (and therefore multiple rows)?

Comment: I want to return one row with the values W3401 3 3/4, 2021-01-18, National Tobacco, 13437, 373, 483. I think if we were able to take the maximum from both of these rows and make that the value for one row, that would be it.

Comment: Have edited is that ok? Bit of an odd grouping, I suggest you think about what you actually want.

Comment: That is it! Thank you so kindly.